# How to query a s3 database from iOS

Tags: ios, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't think I have seen related threads on the forum.

I have a JSON database stored on AWS S3 and I would like to query it from iOS. I don't think Athena can be used on iOS and the only tutorials available between ios and s3 are uploading, or downloading files.

Another solution I think may be possible is to setup an API gateway with a Lambda function, then networking the browser links with iOS (I have not been able to do so, it is probably more complex and doable).

So, how to query a S3 database from ios ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "S3 database". However, Amazon Athena is a service that can run SQL-like commands against multiple objects stored in Amazon S3. Also, [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) can be used to run SQL against a single object in Amazon S3 that can be in various formats (including JSON). You could call those respective APIs.

Comment: Apologies John, I meant query a s3 object that is a JSON database !
I have been able to solve my problem using youtube videos to setup the API Gateway with the Lambda function. 
Instead of using Athena, my process is the following : iOS (decoding a URL) -> API Gateway -> Lambda function -> JSON database on s3.
The function to use in the lambda function to query the JSON object is the AWS function selectObjectContent